# How can I change the format of this input?

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

I have this script in js:

**CODE HTML:**

```
<input class="required-input" type="text" name="date_of_birth" id="date_of_birth" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY">
```

**CODE JS:**

```
$('.required-input').each(function() {
             $(this).on('input keyup keypress blur change', function() {
        const dob=  /^([0]?[1-9]|[1|2][0-9]|[3][0|1])[./-]([0]?[1-9]|[1][0-2])[./-]([0-9]{4}|[0-9]{2})$/;
        var regex;

        if ($(this).attr("id") == "date_of_birth") 
            {
                 regex = dob;
            }

        //SOME CODE JS:

         });
     });
```

I want these things:

1.To be the next format  `23/09/1992`

2.You can not write more characters than necessary.

3.You can not write letters, only numbers

How to change this variable `(dob)` to be good?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why not use jquery date picker instead?

Comment: depending on your browsers that you have to support (based on the `const`, I am guessing that only modern) you can use the input of type `date`. That will take care of most of what you want. It has build in validation. Built right into the browser. This way you don't need regex    http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_input_date

Comment: Your `dob` regex is for DD/MM/YYYY date pattern, but then you have `placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY"`. If you plan to only support `/` delimiters remove others from the `[./-]` class. And `/` must be escaped in a literal notation regex.

Comment: Yes, but for example if a user writes: 23091992...I want to transform this text in 23/09/1992 auto

Comment: Have a look at [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mpdkn4je/). I think it is all you need if you use JQuery.

Answer (score 0):

```
^(19|20)\d\d(/)(0[1-9]|1[012])\2(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])$
```

See [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/dates.html) for more.

---

You can also see
[jQuery Mask](https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/)

---

Consider also using native HTML5 validation attribute:

- [pattern](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_pattern.asp)
- [maxlength](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_maxlength.asp)
- [input type=date](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_date.asp)

Comment: yes but not automatically turn in that format if the user types 23091992

Comment: maybe you need [jQuery Mask](https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/)